# manually play with the physics

Tags: modeling, physics

I'm not sure if this can be done, but I think I've seen videos of someone playing with the cloth sim to make curtains I think, they grabbed the cloth and slid it left and right across something a few times to make it ripple. I'm just wondering if I can do that and how. I want to see if I can do that but do other stuff like that to have more control over the physics.

Comment: If you're talking about household drapes or similar, I did this but not with the cloth sim -   

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkhCKZLZs_Pg0F_aG_HlwziLm0c?e=xaUGQe

Comment: @Edgel3D: i am not sure what you want to achieve with your comment? A video or the result won't help...Or do you want to beg him for more information?

Comment: Hey Alex, I don't know, if you're talking about this tutorial by Andrew Price: [How to Make Realistic Curtains in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3PIlhh9ruw) he's not playing manually with the cloth sim, he's using shape keys with keyframe animation, just like Chris shows in his answer.

Comment: Hi @Chris, You're half right - I've long learned to offer a video clip or BSE link first, particularly when the method demonstrated isn't what's being asked for, such as in this case. Slipping a video up takes no time at all, and some I've offered including this one have been from a previous project and ony need modification and a quick render. (OpenGL)  Those I've created especially such as a recent conveyor belt have sparked my imagination anyway.

Answer (score 4):

1. create a plane, subdivide it with 40

[image]

2. add a vertex group like this:

[image]

3. give the plane a cloth modifier, shape -> pin group: your vertex group from 2
4. add 2 shape keys
5. with second shape key selected change the vertices like this:
   Simply select the upper row, press S and move your mouse
   [image]
6. on frame 1 insert keyframe for value 0

[image]

7. on frame 100 insert keyframe for value 1
8. Shade smooth on plane

result:

[image]

Hint:

i was lazy, all cloth settings were default. So if you want "more action", just change stiffness and the other parameters. And of course you could change your animation speed and/or the vertex locations to your needs. Although changing the subdivisions will change the cloth behaviour! Have fun!

video tutorial: https://youtu.be/P-o_2dgvBAI